# How can I check that the language of one context-free grammar is a subset of a second context-free grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar, parsing

Could you explain me, how can I check, that the language of first context-free grammar (G1) is a subset of the language of second context-free grammar (G2).

G1 and G2 are two LL(1) grammars with identical alphabets:

```
{a, b, c, d, f}
```

Production rules are look like:

```
A -> αB
```

or

```
A -> α
```

and α is a non-epsilon string (of terminal symbols).

Context-free grammar G1:

```
S1 -> aK
K -> bC|cE
C -> cB|d
E -> bA|f
A -> abC
B -> acE
```

Context free grammar G2 :

```
S2 -> aX
X -> bZ|cY
Z -> cV|d
Y -> bU|f
V -> aQ
U -> aP
Q -> cY
P -> bZ
```

**Automatic way is preferred.**

> In additional, how can I check that the languages of two **arbitrary**
>   **context-free grammars** are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m going to rename some of the non-terminals of $G_1$. Specifically, I’m going to change $K$ to $X$, $C$ to $Z$, $E$ to $Y$, $B$ to $V$, and $A$ to $U$:

$$\begin{align*}
&S_1\to aX\\
&X\to bZ\mid cY\\
&Z\to cV\mid D\\
&Y\to bU\mid f\\
&U\to abZ\\
&V\to acY
\end{align*}$$

Now compare this with $G_2$ (where I’ve slightly changed the order in which the productions are listed):

$$\begin{align*}
&S_2\to aX\\
&X\to bZ\mid cY\\
&Z\to cV\mid D\\
&Y\to bU\mid f\\
&U\to aP\\
&P\to bZ\\
&V\to aQ\\
&Q\to cY\\
\end{align*}$$

Apart from the different initial symbols, the first four rows are identical; the only differences are in what can be derived from $U$ and $V$. Can you show that anything derivable from $U$ or $V$ in $G_1$ is also derivable from $U$ or $V$ in $G_2$?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, @Brian. Could you explain me can I do it automatically? And how can I check two arbitrary context-free grammars for their language equality.

Comment: @PuVexi: You’re welcome. In general it’s a very hard problem, and I don’t know any relatively mechanical procedure; this particular problem appears to have been very carefully tailored to make it manageable. Whoever designed it wanted you to recognize that one grammar was almost a copy of the other, just with different names for the non-terminals.